# Json Decode Joomla Params

Tags: json, joomla, parameters

Params:

> `{"calculations":"0","listlayout":"author_items","resetfilters":"1","list_elements":"null","prefilters":"{\"filter-join\":[\"AND\"],\"filter-fields\":[\"uh46v_fb_sw_author_items.category_lev2_raw\"],\"filter-conditions\":[\"equals\"],\"filter-value\":[\"9\"],\"filter-eval\":[\"0\"],\"filter-access\":[\"1\"]}","rows_per_page":"10","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"Food & Beverages","show_page_heading":1,"page_heading":"Food & Beverages","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}`

How can I get the filter-value 9 ? ,`\"filter-value\":[\"9\"]`.

I've tried with Json_decode but it doesn't work.

Comment: that's json embedded in json. You'll have to extract the embedded json from "prefilters", decode it, then get at your filter-value.

Comment: `$foo = json_decode($yourstring); $filters = json_ecode($foo['prefilters']); echo $filter['filter-value']`

Comment: I ve tried this :

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query
    ->select('params')
    ->from('uh46v_menu')
    ->where('id = ' . $db->quote('142')); 
$db->setQuery($query);
$params = $db->loadResult();
$foo = json_decode($params); 
$filters = json_decode($foo['prefilters']);
echo $filters['filter-value'];

and I ve this error :

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: then try `$filters->{'filter-value'}`

Comment: ah, shoot. noticed that filter-value's value is actually an array. `$filters->{'filter-value'][0]` -> 9. in any case, if you'd do a `var_dump($filters)`, you'd see exactly the path you have to take.

Comment: I' done this :

$db = JFactory::getDbo(); $query = $db->getQuery(true); 
$query 
 ->select('params') 
 ->from('uh46v_menu') 
 ->where('id = ' . $db->quote('142'));
$db->setQuery($query); 
$params = $db->loadResult(); 
$foo = json_decode($params);
$filters = json_decode($foo['prefilters']);
var_dump($filters);

Still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some json-object-array manipulations like this:

```
$testString = '{"calculations":"0","listlayout":"author_items","resetfilters":"1","list_elements":"null","prefilters":"{\"filter-join\":[\"AND\"],\"filter-fields\":[\"uh46v_fb_sw_author_items.category_lev2_raw\"],\"filter-conditions\":[\"equals\"],\"filter-value\":[\"9\"],\"filter-eval\":[\"0\"],\"filter-access\":[\"1\"]}","rows_per_page":"10","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"Food & Beverages","show_page_heading":1,"page_heading":"Food & Beverages","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}';

$testString = json_decode(json_decode($testString)->prefilters)->{'filter-value'}[0];
```

$testString will become 9.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Joomla! has a native way for dealing with params... So never - ever json decode params string manually...

Instead do this

```
$paramsString = '{"calculations":"0","listlayout":"author_items","resetfilters":"1","list_elements":"null","prefilters":"{\"filter-join\":[\"AND\"],\"filter-fields\":[\"uh46v_fb_sw_author_items.category_lev2_raw\"],\"filter-conditions\":[\"equals\"],\"filter-value\":[\"9\"],\"filter-eval\":[\"0\"],\"filter-access\":[\"1\"]}","rows_per_page":"10","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"Food & Beverages","show_page_heading":1,"page_heading":"Food & Beverages","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}'

$params = class_exists('JParameter') ? new JParameter($paramsString) : new JRegistry($paramsString);
```

And then retrive a parameter like this

```
$params->get('menu_image', false);
```

The first parameter of the get method is the param you are trying to get, and the second one is the default value - if param doesn't exist or is empty

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do and check how this works like this:

```
$filter = json_decode('{"calculations":"0","listlayout":"author_items","resetfilters":"1","list_elements":"null","prefilters":"{\"filter-join\":[\"AND\"],\"filter-fields\":[\"uh46v_fb_sw_author_items.category_lev2_raw\"],\"filter-conditions\":[\"equals\"],\"filter-value\":[\"9\"],\"filter-eval\":[\"0\"],\"filter-access\":[\"1\"]}","rows_per_page":"10","menu-anchor_title":"","menu-anchor_css":"","menu_image":"","menu_text":1,"page_title":"Food & Beverages","show_page_heading":1,"page_heading":"Food & Beverages","pageclass_sfx":"","menu-meta_description":"","menu-meta_keywords":"","robots":"","secure":0}');

echo '<pre>' ; 
print_r($filter);

$prefilter = json_decode($filter->prefilters);
print_r($prefilter);
```

Now access it like:

```
$prefilter->{'filter-value'}[0] // gives 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're using *(In my case, I'm using a YooTheme Warp Framework-based theme where I am customizing the output of widgets in a custom style, and the widget/module's parameters is exposed as a `Joomla\Registry\Registry` object under `$widget->parameter` as well as a JSON string under `$widget->params`)*, you might be able to get params by calling the appropriate `$obj->get('my_key')` method.